The Pragmatic Maxim as a Maxim of Logic?
Why does the Wikipedia entry on the pragmatic maxim describe it as a "maxim of logic"?

It is not formal logic. It is more akin to Descartes' rules in the Discourse on Method.

This seems to be "logic" in the general sense of ways to think. e.g. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logic definition 1b(1)

Because Peirce uses "logic" in the old sense, the study of Logos, closer to what is now called epistemology and semantics. Pre-20th century philosophers like Kant, Hegel, Peirce, Husserl, routinely used "logic" in this broad sense, see What are the differences between philosophies presupposing one Logic versus many logics? Pragmatic maxim is the centerpiece of Peirce's semantics of concepts.

Logic (proper), as in the logical analysis of natural language and discourse and argument, is just not formal logic: P.F. Strawson, Introduction to Logical Theory, is a great "modern" intro to what Logic actually is.  (I use a capital "L" when there may be confusion.)  Logic proper has simply and mostly been "cancelled"...

Is that the sense in which Peirce used the term logic when he criticized Russell and Whitehead's Principia Mathematica?

Peirce's criticisms of Russell and Whitehead are reviewed by Nubiola, they went far beyond the uses of "logic".

See C.S.Peirce, How to Make our Ideas Clear (1878):

Whoever has looked into a modern treatise on logic of the common sort, will doubtless remember the two distinctions between clear and obscure conceptions, and between distinct and confused conceptions. [...] The very first lesson that we have a right to demand that logic shall teach us is, how to make our ideas clear; and a most important one it is, depreciated only by minds who stand in need of it. To know what we think, to be masters of our own meaning, will make a solid foundation for great and weighty thought.


The principles set forth in the first part of this essay lead, at once, to a method of reaching a clearness of thought of higher grade than the "distinctness" of the logicians.


It appears, then, that the rule for attaining the third grade of clearness of apprehension is as follows: Consider what effects, that might conceivably have practical bearings, we conceive the object of our conception to have [emphasis added]. Then, our conception of these effects is the whole of our conception of the object.

What will be later called the pragmatic maxim is a "rule of method", akin to Descartes' rules (Descartes is explicitly named in the 1878 essays), and thus "logic" is not formal logic but method.
See Peirce’s Early Pragmatism: "In this paper [1878], Peirce introduces a maxim, or principle, which allows us to achieve the highest grade of clarity about the concepts we use. Peirce introduces this principle [...] as a development of the rationalist notion of 'clear and distinct ideas'."
And see Christopher Hookway, The Pragmatic Maxim: Essays on Peirce and Pragmatism (2012).
